# How to validate the tail part of a csv file in a remote server using Java

Tags: java, read.csv

Below are the contents of the CSV file which is generated in hdfs(after running a spark job) then moved to a remote server.

H1|EDHSADB2|2022-08-11 11:10:23|||
H2|RMT_ACC_NM|RMT_ACC_SRT_CD|PDD_TYP_CD|PDD_IGT_VL|REC_LOD_TS
DL|08510968|771103|FPFQP     |{"insights":[{"ACC_NM":"00000000","BNC_CD":"772900","BNM":"LAND SERVICES","TRN_REF_TX":"5404633777075358","PMT_AMT":33.0,"LST_PMT_DT":"2022-08-05","AGG_PMT_AMT":67.18,"PMT_CNT":3},

{"ACC_NM":"00213765","BNC_CD":"802045","BNM":"AQUA MASTERCARD","TRN_REF_TX":"5404633753077758","LST_PMT_AMT":56.78,"LST_PMT_DT":"2022-08-06","AGG_PMT_AMT":272.16,"PMT_CNT":6},

{"ACC_NM":"00213765","BNC_CD":"802045","BNM":"AFIX CARD SERVICES","TRN_REF_TX":"5434298992481650","LST_PMT_AMT":56.78,"LST_PMT_DT":"2022-08-06","AGG_PMT_AMT":272.16,"PMT_CNT":6}]}|
T1|0000000003||||

**How can I extract the Tail information which is 0000000003 above and validate with expected data using Java**.

Comment: Think about how you would extract the information manually. Then write the code to implement it. Then run your code and check the result. If it is not what you want, think harder. Then adjust your code. Then run your code, etc.

Comment: Are you concerned about transfer those files to the app host, read it and extract this field? Do you want to optimize the process or you don't know how to achieve it in anyway?

Comment: @btafarelo I have copied the file to the remote server using hdfs dfs -get command. Next I have to read this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method read your text file in reverse mode, printing only the field required.

It counts the field delimiters | and get the bytes between the forth and fifth delimiters.

**Result**

> 3000000000

**Source**

```
package com.github.btafarelo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class TailFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("/home/btafarelo/tail.txt");

        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");

        long fileLength = file.length() - 1;

        randomAccessFile.seek(fileLength);

        int delimiters = 0;

        char c;

        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

        for(long pointer = fileLength; pointer >= 0; pointer--){
            randomAccessFile.seek(pointer);

            c = (char)randomAccessFile.read();

            if (c == '|') {
                delimiters++;
                continue;
            }

            if (delimiters == 4)
                data.append(c);
            else if (delimiters == 5)
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(data.toString());

        randomAccessFile.close();
    }
}
```